# Is keytool still necessary to create a PKCS12 keystore from a PKCS12 keystore created by OpenSSL from Let's Encrypt pem files?

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, lets-encrypt, keytool

I use Java 11 (AdoptOpenJDK), [keytool uses PKCS12 by default since Java 9](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/229), I need a PKCS12 keystore for Jetty 11. Let's Encrypt gives me two pem files. Therefore, I convert those 2 pem files into a PKCS12 keystore with OpenSSL and I use keytool as advised in [a tutorial](https://www.sorcerers-tower.net/articles/configuring-jetty-for-https-with-letsencrypt):

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domainName/privkey.pem -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domainName/fullchain.pem -out /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domainName/jetty.pkcs12 -passout "pass:$srcKeystorePassword"
keytool -importkeystore -noprompt -srckeystore /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domainName/jetty.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass $srcKeystorePassword -destkeystore /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domainName/keystore -deststorepass $destKeystorePassword
```

Isn't the second line useless (except to use another password)? I can't check it by myself right now because I exceeded the weekly limit of Let's Encrypt yesterday and I didn't keep the created pem files. I wrote [a script to ease self-hosting](https://sourceforge.net/p/red-feed-aggregator/code/ci/master/tree/minimal_self_hosting_setup.sh), I'd like to remove any unnecessary steps from it.

Could I simply copy the PKCS12 keystore created by OpenSSL? Is there anything subtle I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keytool` is necessary for the application servers or softwares supporting only JKS but it's no longer necessary in my case as Jetty 11 supports PKCS12.

Note that `keytool` uses [PKCS12 by default](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/229) since Java 9 (i.e when you don't force the store type) but it was already possible to use this store type as an option with `-storetype pkcs12` [since Java 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyStore) (maybe even in earlier versions).

Comment: Note that the problem isn't with Java - [Java 7 supported `PKCS12` keystores](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) (That's as far back as I went - Java 1.2 might have supported `PKCS12`...).  The problem is with the application doing something like hardcoding `JKS` as the keystore type.

Comment: As far as I remember, there were some notable bugs in PKCS12 support in Java 8: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8193171